# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE selenium java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, instance, program-entry-point

Na hora de executar o programa feito a selenium ele aparace a excessão Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:63)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:275)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
at br.gov.pa.tj.selenium.LancarNavegador.main(LancarNavegador.java:13)

Eu espero corrigir o erro e que o programa rode